# Loading website Images faster

Tags: web, pagespeed

Is it possible to improve Website background image to load faster that it is. My website's background image size is 1258X441 and memory size is 656KB. Its taking too long to load complete background image while accessing my website. Is there anyway than Compressing (As the image is already compressed) to improve its loading speed.

Comment: Compress it more! Jpg should easily get it down to under 100KB

Comment: @Hannesh - I am using PNG :-(

Comment: Don't use PNG. Unless you need transparency, which is ureasonable for background. Use my 2nd point, if you can do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose: (2. is my main solution, and 3.)

1. Compress image even more, because image is background, it doesn't matter that much. Users do not focus at background as much as they do at content.
2. Since background is partially covered by content, you can paint black (or any other solid color) the part of background that is not visible (is behind content). This will make the image compress more nicely, sparig some place.
3. Save image in **JPG progresive** compression. That will make background display in gradually more quality as the image loads.
4. Get rid of background image. (obvious) :)
5. Today's web speeds are big, don't change anything.

**ALSO:** If your PNG image has any repeating parts, you can then slice your image in three parts and spare a lot of space.

Answer (score 1):

The speed of loading the background image is determined by (latency ignored) bandwidth of your connection and the size of the image. So if you have let's say 128 KB/s and an image of size 4096 KB, you at least need

```
4096/128 = 32s
```

for it to load.

Since you can't change the bandwidth, the only thing you can do is change the size of the picture. That is, if you can't compress it more, lower the resolution.

If you don't want to lose precision, you could put different layers of background in your website with different qualities, the better ones over the bad ones. Then when your page is loading, the low quality images load fast and you get some background. Then over time the better quality images load and the background is improved.

Comment: Not true. If you use multiple background, probably many of them will start to load at the same time, worsening the situation (more partially loaded images). The correct alternative is **JPG progresive** compression for that effect.

Comment: @Rok Kralj I'm not such an expert in that and it was just an idea. However, adding one image with 1/4 size, means loading the smaller image 2x faster (because both images are loading at the same time) and the larger image 0.8x faster (so in fact slower). What I mean is, if you get the sizes right, you could get the effect I described which may have a better look even though the overall loading time is increased.

Comment: Also, great mentioning of JPG progressive. That's like what I wanted to simulate, but is already there!

Comment: problem appears that if you have 4 different versions, all four will start to load at the same time (because browsers multithread downloads) and you end even worse. But I appreciate your idea! :)

Answer (score -2):

Load your image in Database and call them , when ever you required. The benefit of this is ? Database is loading once you initiate it and can able to retrieve the information when ever required. it is fast compare to any other technique